# express js total variable query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm worndering, how I could use a hole variable query like this:
/friend/tom/poker/2012/12/01

So that I can say (dynamically), the first param (friend) chooses a folder, the second a js-file, the third a function and the others are params for the function.

Can you follow me?
Like search in folder "friend" for the file "tom.js" and use it's function "poker" with the params (2012, 12, 01)

Is it possible? And how?

Comment: Yes. You just have to parse all the bits of the variable to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
/client/Men/static/2013/02
/client/Women/static/2012/28
```

Solution:

```
/client/:gender/static/:year(\\d{4})/:edition(\\d{2})
```

Use in function:

```
req.params.gender=> Men
req.params.year => 2013
req.params.edition => 02
```

Example:

```
/client/Women/real/dynamic/Site
```

Solution:

```
/client/:gender/:dyn(*)
```

Use in function:

```
req.params.dyn=> real/dynamic/Site
```